# OR some AND rules in OWL API?

Tags: java, owl, owl-api, protege4

I don’t seem to be able to figure out how to OR (`ObjectUnionOf`?) a set of AND (`ObjectIntersectionOf`) rules. What my code produces when the OWL file is opened in protégé is rules (has_difi_min some double[<= "184.84"^^double]) and (has_mean_ndvi some double[<= "0.3428"^^double]), etc. with lines separating the "rulesets" as shown below in the screenshot.

My OWLAPI code:

```
/* write rules */
// OWLObjectIntersectionOf intersection = null;
OWLClassExpression firstRuleSet = null;
OWLClass owlCls = null;
OWLObjectUnionOf union = null;
Iterator it = rules.map.entrySet().iterator();
Set<OWLClassExpression> unionSet = new HashSet<OWLClassExpression>();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
    String currCls = (String) pair.getKey();
    owlCls = factory.getOWLClass(IRI.create("#" + currCls));
    ArrayList<owlRuleSet> currRuleset = (ArrayList<owlRuleSet>) pair.getValue();
    for (int i = 0; i < currRuleset.size(); i++) {
        firstRuleSet = factory.getOWLObjectIntersectionOf(currRuleset.get(i).getRuleList(currCls))
        union = factory.getOWLObjectUnionOf(firstRuleSet);
        manager.addAxiom(ontology, factory.getOWLEquivalentClassesAxiom(owlCls, union));
    }
}
manager.saveOntology(ontology);
```

This is what is looks like:
I want the lines to be ORs.
[image: What it looks like in protege]

edit: Thanks Ignazio!
My OWLAPI code now looks like so:

```
/* write rules */
OWLClass owlCls = null;
OWLObjectUnionOf totalUnion = null;
Iterator it = rules.map.entrySet().iterator();
Set<OWLClassExpression> unionSet = new HashSet<OWLClassExpression>();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
    String currCls = (String) pair.getKey();
    owlCls = factory.getOWLClass(IRI.create("#" + currCls));
    ArrayList<owlRuleSet> currRuleset = (ArrayList<owlRuleSet>) pair.getValue();
    for (int i = 0; i < currRuleset.size(); i++) {
        firstRuleSet = factory.getOWLObjectIntersectionOf(currRuleset.get(i).getRuleList(currCls))
        unionSet.add(firstRuleSet);
    }
    totalUnion = factory.getOWLObjectUnionOf(unionSet);
    unionSet.clear()
    manager.addAxiom(ontology, factory.getOWLEquivalentClassesAxiom(owlCls, totalunion));
}
manager.saveOntology(ontology);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating `unionSet` but not using it. Instead of adding an axiom to the ontology, add `firstRuleSet` to `unionSet`, then create an equivalent class axiom outside the main loop, just before saving the ontology.